# The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, http, dart

```
final dataResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
    Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(dataResponse.body));
```

On nullsafety enabled project, `Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(dataResponse.body));` this code throwing error `The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.`

Followed official [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Following code used for data modeling.

```
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` change to dynamic `fromJson(dynamic json)`

Comment: Your function is working properly my side.

Comment: Are you tried on null safety enabled project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cast your jsonDecode

`Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(dataResponse.body));`

to explicit type:

`Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(dataResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);`

Comment: It needs more modification to fix the error. Inside the Album's fromJson function, change the code to: return Album(
      userId: json['userId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
    );

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to change (Map<String, dynamic> json) to (dynamic json)

```
factory Album.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Code analysis tool says,  Avoid method calls or property accesses on a "dynamic" target.

Answer (score 0):

The model is already good...

Try this.

```
final dataResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
List<dynamic> list =jsonDecode(dataResponse.body);
return list.map((e)=>Album.fromJson(e)).toList();
```